# Full page images defined in nested element

Tags: css

```
#page-background {
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url(/images/background-1600.jpg);
    display: table;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    text-align:center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 25% 50%;
}

#header {
    position:fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    text-align: center;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    height: $header-height;
    width:100%;
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.15) 0%,rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.65) 10%, rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.85) 40%, rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.95) 95%));
    z-index: 9999;
}


#footer {
    position:fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    text-align: center;
    div {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:5rem;
    width:100%;
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.15) 0%,rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.65) 10%, rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.85) 40%, rgba(0, 8, 39, 0.95) 95%));
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

In the HTML the very first thing that is placed is the `#page-background` and it appears that if instead it is placed elsewhere it no longer takes up the whole page. Is there a way to avoid this? By that I mean, add a background image somewhere deeper in the DOM but which -- via *absolute* or *fixed* positioning -- is able to command the entire screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning of an element is always relative to its containing block.

If you use `position: absolute`, the containing block is the padding-edge of the next parent element with `position: relative|absolute|fixed`.

If you use `position: fixed`, the containing block is independent of the element's position in the DOM because the containing block is always the viewport.

I created a simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6s9gx61/1/

Comment: Ok very useful. So for my purposes it appears that 'fixed' is way to achieve the goal. On first stab at doing this, however, I suspect z-index or something is a bit messed up as the image is not visible at all.

Comment: Is it maybe because you didn't use quotes around the url? I added `z-index: -99;` that it is always in background.

Comment: I have tried both. Making a little progress but still not to done ... in any event your answer feels like it's deserving of a check mark. :)